# MVC routing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a custom route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "FabricDetails", // Route name
            "fabric/details/{designerUrlFriendlyName}/{collectionUrlFriendlyName}/{fabricUrlFriendlyName}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Fabric", action = "Details", designerUrlFriendlyName = UrlParameter.Optional, collectionUrlFriendlyName = UrlParameter.Optional, fabricUrlFriendlyName = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
            new[] { "StashFabrics.Web.Controllers" }
        );
```

I have two nearly identical actionlinks and one is working while the other is not

```
@Html.ActionLink(fabric.FabricName, "Details", "Fabric", new RouteValueDictionary(new { designerUrlFriendlyName = fabric.DesignerUrlFriendlyName, collectionUrlFriendlyName = fabric.CollectionUrlFriendlyName, fabricUrlFriendlyName = fabric.FabricUrlFriendlyName }), null)
@Html.ActionLink(fabric.FabricName, "Details", "Fabric", new RouteValueDictionary(new { designerUrlFriendlyName = fabric.DesignerUrlFriendlyName, collectionUrlFriendlyName = "grand_hotel", fabricUrlFriendlyName = fabric.FabricUrlFriendlyName }), null)
```

For whatever reason, as soon as I replace the hard coded value for collectionUrlFriendlyName the link doesn't get built correctly

```
http://localhost:55089/Fabric/Details?designerUrlFriendlyName=jenean_morrison&collectionUrlFriendlyName=grand_hotel&fabricUrlFriendlyName=ballroom_in_azure
http://localhost:55089/fabric/details/jenean_morrison/grand_hotel/ballroom_in_azure
```

This has me stumped. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out.

In the model of the view I have collectionUrlFriendlyName  defined at two different levels; first on the model itself and then again on the class to which the model has a list.

I wasn't defining a value for collectionUrlFriendlyName at the list level, where the URL was being formed. But I guess when constructing the URL it would later find the value at the upper level and use it to form the ugly url (thus hiding the problem that it wasn't populated on the lower level)

If that make sense.